# How to create <input> that works as a link when pressing enter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-applications

I want to be able to typy a `query` into an `<input>` and on pressing enter redirect the user to `\query`.

I know this is quite easy to do with using javascript, but it seems like there should be a better HTML way.

Can you suggest what would be the best practice here? I am using Angular, so if the best way to achieve it is with Angular, it is fine as well.

Comment: redirect to \query or \whatUsersEnter?

Comment: Redirect to \whatUsersEnter

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lsconyer/bktpzgre/1/

Comment: So listen for the keypress, check to see if the keyCode is 13, set the location to the value, seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: and in that example, the doWork() function would probably fire something like a $location.url('http://mylink.com/query?value=' + scope.searchText);

Comment: Hey @Brant the fiddle is great and it seems like a solution. If you post it I will accept.

Comment: While I'd love to take credit, the answer below concerning keypress is the proper way.. Give that guy your upvote.. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for showing me the way, upvoted, will accept as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `ng-keypress` directive within your input tag...

**HTML**

```
<input ng-keypress="goToQueryPage($event)" ng-model="query>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.goToQueryPage = function(keyEvent) {
  if (keyEvent.which === 13)
     alert('Go to ' + $scope.query);
}
```

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mTYmB2nNpos4N5caMaeR?p=preview)

Comment: `ng-keypress` vs `ng-enter` isn't enter better in this case?

Comment: ng-enter is really just a recoding of what ng-keypress is. No need to reinvent the wheel there.

Comment: ng-keypress is core directive on the other hand ng-enter is not of course you can use directives if you will implement that logic at many places but using core directive is much better.

Comment: @bjedrzejewski and if you look at jsfiddle in your comment it was very old and that time angularjs did not have ng-keypress directive at core...